# The following set is connected or not?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space and $S\in \mathcal{L}(E)^+$ (i.e.$S^*=S$ and $\langle Sx\;, \;x\rangle\geq0$ for all $x\in E$).

> Let $U=\{x\in E; \langle Sx\;, \;x\rangle=1\}$. Is $U$ a connected set?

Thank you.

Comment: Let $F = (\ker S)^{\perp}$, and $M$ the unit sphere of $F$. On $M$, define $r(x) = \sqrt{\langle Sx,x\rangle}$ and consider the space $W = \{ x/r(x) : x \in M\}$.

Comment: @DanielFisher Maybe a silly question... We need to have $S$ continuous?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net It's a bounded linear operator so continuous.

Comment: Bounded because symmetric?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Usually, $\mathcal{L}(E)$ denotes the space of continuous linear operators on $E$, and $\mathcal{L}^+(E)$ the subspace of positive semidefinite self-adjoint (self-adjointness follows from $\langle Sx,x\rangle \in \mathbb{R}$ for complex Hilbert spaces) operators, so the boundedness is part of the definition. However, since that hasn't been explicitly stated here, we can - as you suggested - use the Hellinger-Toeplitz theorem to deduce the continuity of $S$.

Comment: @DanielFischer According to your comment $U$ is always connected?

Comment: Unless you belong to those people who consider $\varnothing$ to be disconnected. Then you would need to exclude $S = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. Yes $S$ is not egal to zero. I hope that you write your comment as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F = (\ker S)^{\perp}$. Then $S\lvert_F$ is positive definite, and the function $r \colon M \to (0,+\infty)$ given by $r(x) = \sqrt{\langle Sx,x\rangle}$, where $M$ is the unit sphere of $F$, is continuous.

Hence $W = U\cap F = \{ x/r(x) : x \in M\}$ is homeomorphic to $M$, and since unit spheres in complex normed spaces are connected, $W$ is connected [with the caveat that some people consider $\varnothing$ disconnected, for them we would need to exclude $S = 0$]. And since

$$\langle S(x+y),x+y\rangle = \langle Sx,x\rangle$$

for $y \in \ker F$, it follows that $U$ is homeomorphic to $(\ker S) \times W$, hence connected.

Comment: It's a (complex) topological vector space. All real or complex topological vector spaces are connected, even path-connected. $t \mapsto x + t\cdot (y-x)$ is a path (even an arc) connecting $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Ah thank you. I have now a question in my mind. Do you think that $U$ is also convex?

Comment: $U$ isn't convex, unless it's empty. If we have an $x\in U$, then also $-x$ in $U$, and if $U$ were convex, then $0 = \frac{1}{2}\bigl(x + (-x)\bigr)$ would belong to $U$ too. But of course $\langle S0,0\rangle = 0 \neq 1$. However, if $F$ is infinite-dimensional, then $U$ is homeomorphic to $E$. (That's quite a weird fact, that an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is homeomorphic to its unit sphere, so $W$ is homeomorphic to $F$, and therefore $U \cong W \times (\ker S) \cong F \times (\ker S) \cong E$.)

Comment: Thank you. My last question: why $U$ is homeomorphic to $(\ker S) \times W$? And thank you very much

Comment: The map $(k,w) \mapsto k + w$ is a bijection from $(\ker S) \times W$ to $U$. Since $\alpha \colon (\ker S) \times F \to E$, $\alpha(k,x) = k+x$ is a homeomorphism, its restriction to the (topological, not linear) subspace $(\ker S) \times W$ is a homeomorphism between that subspace and its image.

Comment: Yes, that set is convex. It's the closed unit ball of the seminorm $\lVert S^{1/2}x\rVert$.

Comment: $M$  is the unit sphere of $F$ with repect to the norm of $F$ or the seminorm $\|S^{1/2}x\|$? Thank you

Comment: $M$ is the unit sphere of $F$ with respect to the norm induced by $E$. The unit sphere with respect to $\lVert S^{1/2}x\rVert$ (which is a norm on $F$, since $\ker S^{1/2} = \ker S$) is $W$. And $U$ is the unit sphere of the seminorm $\lVert S^{1/2}x\rVert$ on $E$.

Comment: Thank you for your details. I ask this question because I'm facing difficulties to show that $W$ is homeomorphic to $M$. Could you please help me and thank you

Comment: Since $r\colon x \mapsto \sqrt{\langle Sx,x\rangle}$ is continuous on $E$, and strictly positive on $F\setminus\{0\}$, the map $f_1\colon x\mapsto x/r(x)$ is continuous on $F\setminus\{0\}$. Also, $g_1\colon x\mapsto x/\lVert x\rVert$ is continuous on $F\setminus\{0\}$. Thus the restrictions $f=f_1\rvert_{M}$ and $g=g_1\rvert_W$ are continuous. Then one can check that $f$ and $g$ are inverses of each other. $$g(f(x)) = \frac{f(x)}{\lVert f(x)\rVert} = \frac{x/r(x)}{\lVert x/r(x)\rVert} = \frac{x}{r(x)\lVert x/r(x)\rVert} = \frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert} = x\,$$ since $\lVert x\rVert = 1$ on $M$,

Comment: and $$f(g(x)) = \frac{g(x)}{r(g(x))} = \frac{x/\lVert x\rVert}{\sqrt{\langle S g(x), g(x)\rangle}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{\lVert x\rVert^2\,\langle S(x/\lVert x\rVert), x/\lVert x\rVert\rangle}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{\langle \lVert x\rVert S(x/\lVert x\rVert), \lVert x\rVert(x/\lVert x\rVert)\rangle}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{\langle Sx,x\rangle}} = x$$ since $\langle Sx,x\rangle = 1$ on $W$.

Comment: Since $f^{-1}=g$ and $g^{-1}=f$ I think that $M=W$. Do you agree with me? Thank you

Comment: In general the two sets are different. Consider $Sx = 2x$, then $W = \frac{1}{2}S$.

Comment: Since $f^{-1}\circ g(M)=W$ so $g^2(M)=W$. Thus $h=g^2$ is the homeomorphism between $W$ and $M$. My problem is to find the exact homeomorphism between $W$ and $M$. And thank you for your help.

Comment: The domain of $g$ is $W$, not $M$. So $g(M)$ doesn't really make sense. One homeomorphism (there are lots of others, unless $W = \varnothing$) between $W$ and $M$ is $g$. $g$ maps $W$ homeomorphically to $M$, and its inverse $f$ maps $M$ homeomorphically to $W$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer for **real** Hilbert spaces is no.

Let $S : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ be defined as
$$S(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) = (x_1, 0, 0, \ldots, ) = x_1e_1$$

$S$ is bounded and positive. We have:

$$1 = \langle Sx,x\rangle = x_1^2$$

which implies $x_1 \in \{-1, 1\}$.

Therefore, $U = \{(x_1, x_2, \ldots) \in \ell^2 : x_1 \in \{-1, 1\}\}$.

Note that $U$ is closed since $U = \langle S\cdot, \cdot\rangle^{-1}(\{1\})$.

The sets $\{(-1, x_2, x_3, \ldots ) \in \ell^2\}$ and $\{(1, x_2, x_3, \ldots ) \in \ell^2\}$ are disjoint and both closed in $\ell^2$ so they are in particular closed in $U$.

Comment: $E$ is a complex Hilbert space, so $x_1$ belongs to the unit circle, which is connected.

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought that $x^2 = 1$ implies $x \in \{-1, 1\}$ regardless of field.

Comment: Yes, but in the complex case it's $x_1\cdot \overline{x_1} = 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint (for finite dimensional spaces)**

Using the spectral theorem, you can prove that $U$ is homeomorphic to a product of circles. As a circle is path connected and a product of path connected sets is path connected, $U$ is path connected. Hence connected.